# How to avoid concurrent operations(save/delete) in file operation

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have met a question and need help.

I am designing a simple file service(Http), with which user can upload/download files, as well as deleting files in the file server.

The file service will store files in a single linux computer, under a parent folder(e.g. `/data/fileserver/`). An uploaded file(e.g. `xxx.mp4`) may be saved with the path in computer like `/data/fileserver/demo/1/xxx.mp4`.

The question is that:
**How to avoid concurrent operations(save/delete) in this file service**?

e.g.

User A is uploading file xxx.mp4 and file service is saving(haven't finished) it with path `/data/fileserver/demo/1/xxx.mp4`.

At the same time, user B call `delete api` of this file service to delete the folder `/data/fileserver/demo`. This delete operation will affect the save operation of User A.

I hope in this case the delete operation of User B will fail.

The model seems to lock branch of a tree, but I don't know how to handle.

The file server is based on java language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTTP may be asynchronous, I'd use a design pattern approach.

For instance, you may implement a singleton which handles operations over a determined path.

Let's suppose you don't want the 'fileserver' folder to have any change before the completion of any kind of operation.

Implement a map with the key as the foldername and the value as true or false (meaning on operation or not)

Seems like a simple solution.

Comment: I get the point. It seems need to handle the parent folder with all its sub folers in the map.